# ReCAPTCHA not working

Tags: bug, user-interface, captcha

I was trying to post a question on Stack Overflow, but the ReCAPTCHA was not working. I don't know why. It has been doing this for about a day now. The reason I can post on Meta is because that does not require a ReCAPTCHA. There is no image or box to click. I am on Microsoft Edge on a Windows 11 laptop. How do I fix this?

**Update**: After another day of not being able to post questions, the problem is still persisting.

**Update #2** It still doesn't work, and I tried all of the comments. I don't know what to do now.

[image: This is what my screen shown.]

Comment: "but the ReCAPTCHA was not working" - what exactly does this entail? What steps did you try in order to use it? What did you observe happening as a result, and how is that different from what you expect? (Yes, explaining a bug with Stack Overflow works pretty well the same way as explaining a bug in your code; and others can't really be expected to help without a proper description of the problem.)

Comment: I was just posting a question and then the ReCAPTCHA screen came up with only a box to type things.

Comment: Is your network blocking Google services?

Comment: If you open a new tab and load https://stackoverflow.com/captcha, Hit F12 to get the Developer Tools, find the network tab, then reload the captcha page and share any errors from the network tab or from the console.

Comment: Are you able to access this url https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor ?

Comment: Did you use force-dark flag from your browser? Try disabling that, restarting browser, and then retrying

Comment: *It still doesn't work, and I tried all of the comments*   .... but you didn't share if there are any errors in the developer console, so at best you "tried" some of the comments but you didn't share the outcome of your research.  You are the only one that can deliver the extra info that might help resolve your issue. Editing your question with "Update: doesn't work" while not adding any new info is not going to help anyone.

Comment: While this is a Q/A site, You can reply back to comments... in case you didn't know. Also try a different browser.

Answer (score -5):

You're specifically seeing [this version of recaptcha page](https://support.google.com/recaptcha#6262736), with a top big image widget with no images, and a bottom long textbox.

This is usually shown when the browser doesn't support checkbox widget or has disabled JavaScript. Google recommends

- Using the latest version of your browser
- Disabling plugins/addons
- Enabling JavaScript

You might also try the recaptcha demo page here:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo